# linear independence of $n$ real valued functions is equivalent to independence in $n$ points.

Tags: linear-algebra

For $n>1$ consider $f_1,\,f_2,\,...,f_n\, \in F( \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$. Show that functions $f_1,\,f_2,\,...,\,f_n$ are lineary independent iff there are $n$ pairwise distinct numbers $a_1,\,a_2,\,...,\,a_n$ such that vectors $v_{i}=(f_1(a_i),\,...,\,f_n(a_i))$ are lineary independent. In Kostrikin's book there is hint that if there is linear independence then there exist such $a_1$ that $f_1(a_1) \neq 0$ and to prove the theorem by induction and using independence of $f_i-\frac{f_i(a_1)}{f_1(a_1)}\cdot f_1$ but I can't see how to prove that thorem  using that hint. I have already seen this proof linked below, but I'd love to understand Kostrikin's prove. Any help will be greatly apprecied. 
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679057/linearly-independent-functionals?fbclid=IwAR3DiHEvw4ExdjfbYfGyRUytJhGd-3mXCPyi23S5Nhb5Rm_5gHsqZS1M0SM}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679057/linearly-independent-functionals?fbclid=IwAR3DiHEvw4ExdjfbYfGyRUytJhGd-3mXCPyi23S5Nhb5Rm_5gHsqZS1M0SM%7D)